# App keeps coming into foreground even after closing from task manager, how to close manually?

Tags: android, react-native

Hello I am adding sound playing functionality into my app and I've decided to use [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player) I have successfully installed it and I am following the examples. Whenever I play a sound clip, I see the "play" icon at the very top of the status bar and a compact notification appears. The clip plays fine and I can place the app in the background. The issue is whenever I try to close the app via the task manager (square button). Ill see the play icon disappear for a couple of seconds but then my app restarts and comes into the foreground again.

I am not really familiar with the Android APIs therefore I am unable to dive into the native code. So what I would like to do is listen for when the app is close (closed from the task manager, not suspended) and then stop and destroy the player manually to close the app.

Here are the relevant packages

```
"react-native-track-player": "github:react-native-kit/react-native-track-player#dev",
"react-native": "0.51.0",
"react-native-navigation": "^1.1.334",
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright my issue stemed from the fact that the background service my app was starting was not stopping when the app stopped. How I solved this was to modify the AndroidManifest.xml of the third party service. I added the `android:stopWithTask="true` attribute to the service tag. Now its declaration look like this.

`<!-- The service for the headless tasks in which events can be received by the JS side -->
    <service android:name=".logic.services.PlayerTask" android:stopWithTask="true" android:enabled="true" />`

Hope to be someones beacon of light in the future. Thanks